# Error when I try to run `npm run test` in windows command prompt

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I tried to run `npm run test` on my directory but I get an error in the terminal that says:

`'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I searched around but the only thing I got close to the problem is [this](https://github.com/tarmolov/git-hooks-js/issues/36) but there's nothing there that can help me fix it.

My `OS` is **Windows 10** and the `npm` version is **8.1.0**
[image: npm-run-test-error-message]

Below is the content of the **package.json** file found inside the directory.

```json
{
  "name": "angular-project-1",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs --recursive --reporter spec",
    "test:part2": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part2/ --recursive --reporter spec",
    "test:part3": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./src/spec/mocha-specs/part3/ --recursive --reporter spec",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.0",
    "@phenomnomnominal/tsquery": "2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.1",
    "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
    "cssom": "0.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should also include the `test` script inside your `package.json` file.

Comment: Hi @OctavianMărculescu I've included the contents of the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the **dot** (**.**) located before the entry directories called `/node_modules` and `/src`.

So this was **before** it was fixed:

```json
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha /src/spec/mocha-specs --recursive --reporter spec",
"test:part2": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha /src/spec/mocha-specs/part2/ --recursive --reporter spec",
"test:part3": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha /src/spec/mocha-specs/part3/ --recursive --reporter spec",
```

And this is **after** it is fixed:

```json
"test": "/node_modules/.bin/mocha /src/spec/mocha-specs --recursive --reporter spec",
"test:part2": "/node_modules/.bin/mocha /src/spec/mocha-specs/part2/ --recursive --reporter spec",
"test:part3": "/node_modules/.bin/mocha /src/spec/mocha-specs/part3/ --recursive --reporter spec",
```